# Customizing time parsing in Moment JS

Tags: javascript, datetime, momentjs

I am trying to customize the output of a timestamp using **MomentJS**. Using relative time I can get `... mins ago`, `... hour ago` etc. Using calendar I get `Today at ...` or `HH:MM` etc.

But what I want is the following for a certain timestamp:
`Just a second ago`,
`1 min ago`,
`2 min ago`,
`3 min ago`,
`...`,
`10 min ago`,
`HH:MM`,
`YESTERDAY`,
`DD/MM/YYYY`.

I can't understand whether it is even possible using this library.

I have tried the following:

```
  var time1 = moment.unix(1509711336).fromNow();
  var time2 = moment.unix(1509711336).calendar();
  var time3 = moment.unix(1509711336).format('HH:MM');
```

**DEMO:** [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ayan/9Lhyr8r3/)

**UPDATE:** suppose I post an article, then the time should read as `Just a second ago`, then **upto 10 mins** or so it should read as `1 min ago`, `2 min ago`, `3 min ago` and so on. After that it should read as `HH:MM`. Then when we move to next day it should give only `YESTERDAY` and then after that day it should print `DD/MM/YYYY`.

Comment: It's really not very clear what your trying to achieve here

Comment: I get your point, but it would require quite alot of ugly `if`'s

Comment: what is the expected output?

Comment: Are you okay with using another library like https://www.npmjs.com/package/moment.twitter ?

Comment: @krishnar I have posted the required output in y question.

Comment: @MarkCooper, I am completely comfortable as long as it goes with react-native

Comment: .fromNow();    is giving output in a way which you want

Comment: @krishnar, it's not quite the same, but it's similar as far as I have seen.

Comment: @krishnar, Ok, suppose I post an article, then the time should read as `Just a second ago`, then upto 10 mins or so it should read as `..mins ago`. Then it should print the `HH:MM`. Then when we move to next day it should give only `YESTERDAY` and then after that day it should print `DD/MM/YY`

Comment: @Ayan   then update your question with above comment. Its difficult to understand.

Comment: @krishnar, updated the question.

Comment: @MarkCooper, Does the library exactly the way I want?

Comment: right so less than 60 seconds you want x seconds > 60 seconds you want y minutes > 10 minutes your want hh:mm, etc. Correct? What's wrong with `if` statements?

Comment: @Liam Yes! correct. There is no wrong with `if` statements, but I want to know is there any other cleaner options using this library?

Comment: I believe not. A few if statements seems pretty clean to me...?

Comment: @Liam, well using relative time I get a string. How do you want me to implement the check?

Comment: `moment().toDate()` will give you a date object you then just get todays date and compare. Moment also has a series of [query methods](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/) you can use

Comment: @Liam, I am not sure though, but am trying. Still a snippet would be helpful.

Comment: @Ayan, what you're looking for is what I've always seen referred to as '[Twitter Time](https://www.sitepoint.com/calculate-twitter-time-tweet-javascript/)' and there are piles of libraries out there that handle it for you if you don't want to roll your own (see the answer already given).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var customFn = {
    sameDay: function(now) {
      if (Math.abs(this.diff(now)/1000)<60) {
      console.log()
        return '['+this.fromNow()+']';
      } else {
        return 'HH:MM';
      }
    },
    lastDay: '[Yesterday]',
    lastWeek: '[Last] dddd',
    sameElse: 'DD/MM/YYYY'
  }
  var time1 = new moment().calendar(null, customFn);
  var time2 = moment.unix(1509711336).calendar(null, customFn);
  var time3 = moment.unix(1509580800).calendar(null, customFn);
  var time4 = moment.unix(1507593600).calendar(null, customFn);
  $('#displayTime1').text(time1);
  $('#displayTime2').text(time2);
  $('#displayTime3').text(time3);
  $('#displayTime4').text(time4);
});
```

```css
.display {
  background-color: lightgray;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.19.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<div class="display" id="displayTime1"></div>
<div class="display" id="displayTime2"></div>
<div class="display" id="displayTime3"></div>
<div class="display" id="displayTime4"></div>
```

You can modify [calendar](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/calendar-time/) according to your use. Took diff solution from @krishnar. Thanks.

Comment: nice one :) For minutes do I use `minutes` or `min`?

Comment: minutes is okay;)

Answer (score 3):

define your own method inside moment library like this.

```
moment.fn.fromNowOrNow = function (a) {
    t = Math.abs(moment().diff(this) / 1000) 
    if (t < 60) { 
        return 'just now';
    }else if(t> 60 && t<36000){
      return this.fromNow(a);  
    }else if(t> 36000 && t<86400){
      return this.format("hh:mm")
    }
    this.fromNow(a);  

}
```

now you can call this method like

```
moment().fromNoworNow()
```

**NOTE:: You can put some more conditions like above**

Comment: I think the only thing you're missing, which is the trickiest bit, is the 'Yesterday' condition.